# C# sentence into a string

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to code a Discord bot but my C# is a bit rusty at the moment. I'm trying to make it so someone can send an alert to the admin console by doing a command in a channel.

The commands work by doing -conalert (the message) but, at the moment it only works if it's a one-word message.

I remember using this function for a similar project that I since have lost and it worked like a charm.

```
[Command("conalert")]
public async Task conalert(string msg)
{
  EmbedBuilder conalert = new EmbedBuilder();
  Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `[Remainder]` attribute:

```
public async Task conalert([Remainder]string msg)
```

A more complete interesting example is here: https://www.gngrninja.com/code/2019/4/1/c-discord-bot-command-handling